# Which AWS EC2 instance to choose?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-ec2, production

I have a Node.js REST API which is expected to serve a total of approx 3000 requests(inbound+outbound) per day, in production. Which EC2 instance type would be the most appropriate choice for this kind of an app? I'm confused between t2.small and t2.medium and how many should I setup into the load balancer?

Comment: t2.small and t2. medium are not use for handling request. if you want to handle request , you use load balancer

Comment: Yes, but the load balancers have to redirect traffic to ec2 instances right? So my question is what type of instances and how many should I setup?

Comment: Really sorry for leaving out that part in the main question previously.

Comment: Please use EB for handling request

Comment: `t2` are already deprecated, use `t3` instead, better resources for a cheaper price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `t3.nano` can also be enough as the number of requests are very low. Regarding how many, I would always have minimum 2 instances against load balancer in different avaialbility zones. e.g if you are using `eu-west-1` region then 1 box can go in `eu-west-1a` and second in `eu-west-1b`.